# non-owner users cannot edit or execute store procedures through Workbench interface

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

We have several stored procedures in our database, and they were created with the root user as the definer. Currently, all users can successfully invoke and execute these stored procedures using the CALL method. However, non-root users encounter issues when trying to access these procedures through graphical interfaces like Workbench or Navicat.

Specifically, non-root users are unable to interact with the procedures through the Workbench or Navicat interfaces. Despite granting all the necessary privileges required for routines to our users, they still face limitations when it comes to working with procedures through these graphical tools. Users can perform various actions on tables and views without any problems, but they encounter restrictions when attempting to work with procedures.

We've also experimented by creating test procedures with different non-root users, and in those cases, only the root user and the user who created the procedure can access and manipulate the procedures through the Workbench interface.

I am adding more information here. Here is the create statement:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `p_contact_lookup`(
    IN contactid VARCHAR(8)
)
BEGIN...
```

Here is my privileges for the users.

```
GRANT EXECUTE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE ROUTINE ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

Also, I have created these procedures with root user because cloudsql would not allow me to create it with a non-root user even if that non-root has 'ALL PRIVILEGES' except CLOUDSQLSUPERUSER privileges.

I hope this adds more clarity. Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave more specific symptoms for the "issues". Any error message shown? As it is likely a permission issue, please show the grant statements you have executed for the non-root users.

Comment: Thanks slaakso for the comment. The users dont get any error. The Workbench/Navicat interface just would not do anything. "CALL myproc()" works just fine for all.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the `PROCEDURE`, include `SQL SECURITY` clause.  You seem to have `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` and be creating as "root".  Be cautions; this is dangerous because errors in the proc can lead to serious damage.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE PROCETURE ...`

Also `GRANT` the `EXECUTE` privilege to the invoker. else the user cannot `CALL` the proc.

Please provide `SHOW GRANTS FOR ...`  Example:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR forest@localhost;
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for forest@localhost                                |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `forest`@`localhost`                 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `forest`.* TO `forest`@`localhost` |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Rick. I added more information to the post.  The user can call the procedure with this command "CALL myprod('')" but he cannot call it from Workbench/Navicat interface. My users find it difficult to know all the parameters and they want to use the interface and not the CALL method.

Comment: What MySQL "user" does Workbench/Navicat connect with?